# DateTimePicker control freezes

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a problem. I've setup the maxdate value of the DateTimePicker to 31/12/2030. In realtime when i click on the top left icon of the DateTimePicker the control freeze itself for awhile and after it changes the page to previews month the date it's set automatically to its maxdate value. If i set the max date to a greater date (ex. 31/12/2100) the control freeze for 5-6 seconds. What is happening?

*PS: I'm working on C# WinForms.*

*Edit:*

The DateTimePicker object is called "dela". The code that i wrote for this object is...

```
private void dela_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            KeyUpDown = true;
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            KeyUpDown = true;
            break;
     }
}
private void dela_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (KeyUpDown == false)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("Right");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? It sounds like you may have attached the wrong code to an event or something.

Comment: @valy.maties..! Would you please test the scenario in a separate solution/project with no extra line of codes? And post back the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here but it could be your `dela_ValueChanged` function is getting called on repeat with KeyUpDown not being set. So this means it's repeatedly doing `SendKeys.Send("Right")` (presumable this changes the date 1 day forward?) until it hits the final date when it's trying to change past the final date which it can't so it's not changing it's value, thereby getting out of the loop.

Comment: I have presumed that user press numeric keyboard to change the value of date. If object have focus on day part of control and the value is changed automatically the focus is changed to month part of object.  If i press up or down key the focus will not change and the part of datetimepick object who have focus will be incremented or decremented succesfully without loosing focus. How can i know if the value was changed from keyboard or from mouse?

Comment: ValueChanged will activate whenever the value for your DateTimePicker is changed, i.e whenever the date changes, so it doesn't care whether it is a keyboard or mouse event. You can use the MouseClick event to register when the control is clicked by the mouse.

Comment: Thanks @judgeja , i added a new boolean MousePressed, which will be false in KeyDown event and true in MouseDown event. In this way i check if KeyUpDown is false and MousePressed is false. It seems to work good.

Answer (score 0):

"Sendkeys.send("/")" in valuechanged event of datetimepicker.